# Error aplicando lapply en un for loop en R ¿Cómo corregirlo?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, loops

Intento aplicar una función sencilla de normalización a las variables numéricas de la base de datos `iris` de R a través de un `for` y usando `lapply` con el fin de obtener una nueva base de datos que contenga sólo las variables normalizadas:

```
data(iris)

normal <- function (x) {
num <- x - min(x)
den <- max(x) - min(x)
return (num/den)
}

iris_n <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(iris)){
if (is.numeric(iris[,i])) {
}
iris_n[,i] <- as.data.frame(lapply(iris[,i], normal))
}

Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors
Además: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

iris_n

[1] NaN.   NaN..1 NaN..2 NaN..3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Ahora bien, intento hacer lapply directamente con:

```
iris_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(iris, function(x) {if (is.numeric(x))  normal(x)}))

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 150, 0
```

Por más que le doy vuelta no logro encontrar el error. Cualquier orientación será muy apreciada (Ojo: me interesa resolver este problema en específico, sé que existen otro tipo de soluciones para lograr lo que necesito)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Son muy buenas las opciones que te da Patricio y explican bien como funcionan las `*apply()`.

Dos alternativas:

Si no sabes de antemano qué variables no son numéricas como para descartarlas directamente en la llamada a la función puedes aplicar la función solamente a las numericas de este modo:

```
    lapply(iris[sapply(iris, is.numeric)], normal)
```

`sapply()` es pariente de `lapply()`, sólo que regresa un vector en lugar de una lista. En este caso la usamos para que pregunte a iris qué columnas son numéricas (esas regresan `TRUE`, las que no lo son regresan `FALSE`). Como está dentro de los corchetes se utiliza para "recortar" los datos, quedando solamente las numéricas. Luego `lapply()` se encarga de aplicar a esas `normal` y recibes una lista fácil de coercionar a `data.frame`. Eso sí, pierdes el factor `Species`.

Si no tienes problema en usar un paquete aparte hay una opción de sintaxis muy clara usando la librería `purrr`. La función que reemplaza a `lapply()` o `apply()` para este caso es `modify_if()`. Como su nombre lo indica modifica un elemento de una lista (iris es una lista porque todos los data.frame son listas, aunque no todas las listas son data.frame) **si** se cumple una condición. En este caso, que sea numérica la columna. Lo interesante es que conserva intactas a las columnas en las que no se cumple la condición.

Otra característica particular de `modify_if()` y de toda la flia. `modify_*` es que intenta regresarte los datos con la misma estructura que entran. Es decir, si la función recibe un data.frame -en este caso, `iris`- procurará regresarte otro data.frame. No es necesario `as.date.frame()` después. Así de elegante:

```
library(purrr)
modify_if(iris, is.numeric, normal)
```

Normalizados y con todas las columnas originales.

Sin embargo creo que la mejor opción, si estás dispuesto a cargar un paquete extra, es usar `dplyr::mutate_if()`.

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, normal)
            #condición  #función
```

Esta te garantiza que el resultado es un data.frame o un error. Eso puede ser mejor de lo que suena...

Comment: ¡Gracias! Justo lo que buscaba y aparte con ganancia. Saludos :)

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, tienes este problema:

```
 Error in Summary.factor(1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors
```

Que se debe a que en tú código `lapply()` también se está aplicando sobre los valores de la columna `Species` que es un factor, la llamada a `lapply()` deberías hacerla dentro del bloque del `if (is.numeric(iris[,i]))`

El otro problema son los valores `Nan` que se generan. Esto se debe a un comportamiento algo discutible de **R** cuando se recortan objetos mediante indices `[]`. Cuando recortas una matriz o un objeto similar tomando una sola fila o una sola columna, **R** "coerciona" por defecto el valor de retorno a un tipo más primitivo, en este caso un vector. Lo que produce que `lapply`se aplique sobre cada elemento del vector, lo que termina generando una división por 0 y por consiguiente los `Nan`

Para evitar esto, así como tienes escrito el código, simplemente podrías hacer:

```
lapply(iris[,i,drop = FALSE],normal)
```

o

```
lapply(iris[i],FUN=normal)
```

Por último, el problema de hacer esto:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(iris, function(x) {if (is.numeric(x))  normal(x)}))
```

Es que una de las columnas, la de `Species` no la estás retornando, entonces tienes 4 listas con 150 elementos y una con ninguno, por lo cual obtienes el error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 150, 0
```

Lo solucionas retornando `normal(x)`para las columnas numéricas y directamente `x` para las que no lo son. Resumiendo, to tu código puede sintetizarse en esto:

```
iris_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(iris, function(x) {if (is.numeric(x)){normal(x)}else{x}}))
```

Comment: La cuestión es que quiero que el código trabaje suponiendo que no sabemos cuáles son las variables numéricas, de ahí que haya incluido el is.numeric, aunque supongo que la solución sería la misma, solo señalando esa condición, ¿no?

Comment: acabo de poner un agregado a la respuesta de Patricio y creo que atiende este comentario. Los bucles `for` son tentadores porque parecen intuitivos (le digo qué hacer en cada momento). Pero al la larga son más trabajosos que una vectorizada tipo `*apply`. Yo los evito a menos que sean imposible hacer algo de otra manera.

Comment: Gracias a ambos. Siempre tan gentiles :)

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera, efectivamente usando el `isnumeric()` puedes evitar el error, aunque sigues teniendo el problema de aplicar `lapply()` como lo estas haciendo. Saludos.

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera, revisa mi edición, pasé por alto el verdadero problema de tu código. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Patricio. Se aprende siempre mucho de tus respuestas. Saludos :)